# Google Visualization - Bar Chart Backwards Axis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am rendering a bar chart but, even though my data is sorted correctly (and appearing with the correct sort order, largest to smallest), my axis is backwards by default.

I have tried changing the values in the chart `options` for both `hAxis` and `vAxis` and I can not get this to reverse to the correct direction (low to high).

My other properties in `options` are working fine.

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: Backwards Axis]

Answer (score 0):

For the hAxis, what's it set to now? Did you try:

```
{direction: -1}
```

Comment: My hAxis is defined as the following ... the gridlines property is being recognized (it has a visible effect), the direction is not:                 hAxis: {
                    gridlines: {
                        color: 'transparent'
                    },
                    direction: -1
                }

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by making sure the chart was seeing my numbers as `number` and not as `string`.

First, define your column as a number:

data.addColumn('number', 'Your Column Name');

Then, if your "number" is actually a string in JavaScript, you'll need to convert this using `parseFloat()` before attempting to add a row to the `dataTable`.

This has fixed the reverse-axis issue for me.